# DIV colliding with TABLE in pure html

Tags: html, html-table

In the below code, the `table` which is supposed to be below the `div` ends up colliding with it and showing up in the middle of it.

Any help is welcome.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8dra/)

```
<div id="header" width="100%">
    <center>
        blabla
    </center>
    <table align="left" class="header"> 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Links</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="blabla">blabla</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="blabl">blabla</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="blabla">blabla</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table align="right" class="header">    
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>contacts</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="mailto:adude">this guy</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="mailto:anotherdude">that other guy</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>the table that shouldn't be here</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to "clear: both" when you don't want an element to be affected by other elements' float value (or align in this case).

Here is what is happening, your first table is attached to the left, your second to the right, and the third is trying to fit between the two.

You can tell the third table to find an empty line to start on by using `style="clear: both"`

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8dra/4/).

notice the:

```
style = "clear: both"
```

on the bottom table

Comment: I'm running into the issue that when I apply borders to the containing `div`, the tables are not included anymore but that's for an other thread.

Answer (score 0):

**A couple of things:**

1. You're using `<center>`, which is deprecated, [according to
       W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center):

   > The  element was introduced in HTML 3.2 - Block elements. It
   >   has been deprecated since HTML 4 - 15.1.2 Alignment.
   >
   > HTML5 classifies it as a non-conforming feature.
2. In the jsfiddle you linked, the table seems to be below the div, so
           I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you clarify?